# SQL Insert a new row into an existing table changing all but one column

Tags: sql

I have a table with 14 columns. The first column is Part #. I need to insert a new line and add different data to the other 13 columns if the data in column 10 is different.

For example:

```
Part #  Description Lead Time   Price 1 Price 2 Price 3 Min. Buy    Date    ATA
1693    SHORTY PLUG     045  $-      $-      $4.25  100 110612  STC
2617    DOME PLUG            045     $-      $-      $0.75   100    111912  CIS
2617    DOME PLUG            045     $-      $-      $0.50  100 91012   STC
2617    DOME PLUG            045     $-      $-      $0.50  100 91012   STD
2646    PLUG (BLACK 045  $-      $-      $6.75  100 91012   STC
2646    PLUG (BLACK)    045  $-      $-      $6.00  100 91012   STD
```

The key column is the "ATA" column. How would I add, say Part # 2646 which had an ATA Code of "CIS". The Part # is the only Column which will stay the same. I want to leave the other Rows in the table, just add another row with a Part # of 2646 with the rest of the data different.

I'm not very proficient in SQL, and have tried everything I can find on the Internet with no success. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What should happen with the old row `2646`?

Comment: Are you running into an error?  Is your Part# a `PRIMARY KEY`, thus your problem?

Comment: Please specified the DBMS (SqlServer, Oracle..etc). What happen for the case "column 10 is **not** different"?

Comment: Please be more specific about what you want. Also, add any example code. Finally, see the [Stack Overflow Newbie Guide](http://grahn.us/projects/stack-overflow.php). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @screenmutt when you go to that newbie page and scroll to the bottom and click the link for your website, it goes to the site but the body of the page is a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need a simple insert statement.  Replace the values part with the actual values you want to add to your database table.

```
Insert into YOUR_TABLE ([Part #], [Description], [Lead Time], [Price 1], [Price 2], [Price 3], [Min. Buy], [Date], [ATA])
Values (OLD_PART_NO, NEW_DESCRIPTION, NEW_LEAD_TIME, NEW_PRICE_1, NEW_PRICE_2, NEW_PRICE_3, NEW_MIN_BUY, NEW_DATE, NEW_ATA)
```

Comment: That is non-standard SQL (and currently the question is still tagged with SQL, not with a specific DBMS product)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name True, but since those column names need to be "escaped" I just picked MSSQL because it is the one I'm most familiar with.  If the question gets updated for a specific DBMS I'll update my answer.  Until then this will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a table where you can have multiple items with the same part number but must vary on a second column and still want to prevent duplicates you need to edit your PRIMARY KEY to include both the `Part #` and the `ATA` columns like so:

```
ALTER TABLE [name]
DROP CONSTRAINT [pk_constraint_name] [or DROP PRIMARY KEY for MySQL]

ALTER TABLE [name]
ADD PRIMARY KEY([Part #],[ATA])
```

Or you could have another column be the primary key and then define a `UNIQUE INDEX` on those two columns, either would likely have the desired end result.